# Schengen visa to study in Germany refused

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, study, visa-refusals

I'm from Philippines and currently employed as a nurse here in my country. I applied for a Schengen visa to study German language for 3 months.  Unfortunately, my application was refused under the following circumstances:

1. The information presented regarding the justification of my stay was not reliable
2. I have not proven enough fund to cover my expenses during my stay there
3. I was not able to satisfy them about my willingness to return to my home country before my visa expires.

Anyone who has a good idea on what right approach should I take.

Comment: The purpose of my stay was not substantiated by the documents presented. I presented the confirmation letter sent bu the school containing the following details: paid 3 months tuition fee for a six months language course program, have a reserved room at the campus..

Comment: I'm surprised your school didn't advise you on the right type of visa to apply for. The Schengen visa is only for short stays (you can only stay for 90 days in any 180 day period).

Answer (score 6):

Item 2 is pretty self-explanatory, you need more money in your bank account or evidence of salary being paid while you travel.  You can pad your account with money from family or friends, but don't just put one big lump sum in, as consular officials are wise to that trick.  Add the money in smaller chunks over several weeks.

Item 3 is a sticking point for many visa applications for people from developing or third world countries.  They want to see evidence you are motivated to return home.  This can include owning a house, children or parents that you support / take care of, a very desireable job that is guaranteed for your return, etc.  And unfortunately, these can sometimes be hard to document (except owning your own house).

Comment: My leave is actually without pay and I don't own a house I live with my parents, being the last child its my job to look after there well being since my two siblings are bought working outside our city. Do you think a letter from my employer assuring them of my return due to my current job will help?

Comment: And someone told me to open a german account is it necessary for this kind of visa?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no set rules on exactly what the consular official will need. They look at the sum of all documents and make a decision. Everything you can think of should be submitted, a letter from your employer is good, a letter from a village official attesting that you take care of your parents, anything that shows ties to home.

Comment: I haven't also presented a letter regarding my intention of studying the language do I also need to justify that?

Comment: Anything you can think of that shows your reason to visit and your reason to return home will be helpful.  The more documentation you can show the better your chances are.

Comment: @Betynka Tom's advice is good but unfortunately, in your situation, you need to be prepared for the fact that they might reject your application nonetheless.

Comment: @Relaxed, Tom didn't address reason #1. Without fixing that, the other stuff doesn't come in to play.

Comment: @gayot - Item #1 was difficult to address, as we didn't know what Betynka submitted.  But was mentioned during the comment conversation, that she should submit everything related to why she is traveling there.  But #3 is by far the biggest reason for visa rejection for people coming from developing and third world countries.

Comment: @Tom, can you point me to the statistics on 'by far the biggest reason...'.  I would love to see them!

Comment: @gayot - I don't know of any published "statistics", I only know what has happened to people I know and comments from folks who work at the consulates (off the record chat over drinks, not official statements).  Of course I also know that this lack of some internet "proof" will not satisfy the nitpickers here.  But sorry I am old fashion, I answer questions based on my own knowledge, not something I goggled.

Comment: @Tom, that's got to be one ENORMOUS amount of drinks with a whole lot of people...  And all 'off the record'?  Remarkable!  :)

Comment: Beer is cheap where I live and I have lived a long time ;-)

Comment: Indeed.  Most of the time people on the net who make broad and inaccurate statements cite private, unofficial sources. Such people are generally trying to add weight to their assumptions by claiming 'insider knowledge'. Otherwise your 'unofficial sources' would have pointed out that yes, statistics ARE published.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide evidence to the contrary, that my statements and personal knowledge are wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Tom already provided good advice (+1 to his answer) but I just noticed your comment. You apparently submitted documentation (leave from your work, tuition fees and funds) for a three-month stay while registering to a six-month program that you cannot possibly complete on a short-stay visa. That's a big no-no that would make your application look very suspicious. It must have looked like this language program is just a pretext for you to enter Germany and do something else during these three months or even stay illegally in the country after that.

Beside following Tom's advice, you definitely need to either find a three-month program or apply for the right type of visa (and even that might be difficult in your situation).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should apply for a student visa, not a Schengen visa. 
Schengen visa is for short stays only, usually with the main purpose of tourism. A different visa applies for those who plan to study in the EU. :)